# Python Tornado file download

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I have multiple files in different directories that I need to users to be to access from a web page. They can view all text files within the browser but will download all *.zip files. I having difficulty with my code below in Python & Tornado for downloading the files

```
if directory.endswith('.zip'):
    print('Currently downloading:', url)
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    self.set_header("Content-Description", "File Transfer")
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename {}'.format(directory))

    with open(url, 'r') as f:
        try:
            while True:
                data = f.read(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                self.write(data)
            self.finish()
        except Exception as exc:
            self.write(json_encode({'data': exc}))
```

I have looked at a lot of posts online and they suggest to do as I am doing but yet I am not getting the right results.

Please advise

Comment: FYI.. files that need to be downloaded are not in on static folder, they are all over the root directory

Comment: what are your "results"? do you have a specific error message? if your files are not in a static folder then you have to make each file itself static to make it accessible.

Comment: The main reason to use the Tornado is its asynchronous nature, and in this there is no code asynchrony. Moreover you block tornado until not give the file. Look source implementation StaticFileHandler it will give a very detailed understanding why you wrote the wrong code and blocking main event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the reason it was not working, I was sending the request using Ajax JQuery, which was getting the response and didn't know what to do with, so instead I just submitted the form and the file downloaded properly.